# I struggle with rigging

Tags: rigging, bones

I struggle with rigging. I need two pivot points on a model, the problem is, the bones doesn't follow each other. If i put the second bone as parent for the first bone, it's okay, the first bone will follow the second one. But the second one won't follow the first. Here's a screenshot to help you to understand my problem.[image: Blender Edited Screenshot]

On this image, for example : the expected comportement is :

1 - I rotate the first bone on the z axis by 180d, so the plane move on the green circle.

2 - The second bone follow the movement and move along the red circle (rotate on z axis, by 180d and the pivot point is the actual position of the first bone).

3 - Now, the schema is "inverted"

4 - I rotate the second bone on the z axis by 180d, so the plane move on the blue circle.

2 - The first bone follow the movement and move along the pink circle (rotate on z axis, by 180d and the pivot point is the actual position of the second bone).

Like this, i can easily make this as a loop. I need to animate the first bone, then the second one.. and another time the first one. Like this, the object move forward, rotation per rotation.

I've tried some modifiers, like "copy rotation" or "Pivot" but it seems to mess up and my bones have weird rotations. I've tried to parent them with others "abstract" bones, but since i can't have parents loops, it doesn't work.

I see a post here [on blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/rig-object-with-two-multiple-pivot-points/1299954) but it's not really my problem.

Comment: you cannot have a so called "circular dependency" because it makes less sense. What is a circular dependency? if a is parent of b is parent of c is parent of a (in your easier case: a parent of b is parent of a). Because you have to calculate it somehow. And then the order of your calculation would matter. And if you calculate again in a different order, the result would be different. The solution for u in your easy case would be to use child of constraint and use the influence to turn on/off the constraints as you need it.

Comment: Yes that's what i'm doing actually, i use Dynamic parents add-on to make it easier. If i animate the "Child Of" constraints, blender doesn't keep the child position when i change the parent. With this add-on, it calculate the new position automatically, make it easier !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the add-on "Dynamic Parent" solve my problem. I can now make animations with changes on the "Child of" Modifier Value. The add-on recalculate the child position when i change the parent value.

Without this add-on, the position of the child is reset during the animation.

Link to this add-on [on Github](https://github.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent)